# Neo4j database execution error searching against an index with a node name containing a space

Tags: neo4j

I'm playing around with neo4j community edition 2.0.1, and I've struck a problem which I can't find a solution to.  My ineptitude with Cypher may be contributing to my issues!

I have a small number of nodes, with an index on a "Name" property.  For demonstration purposes, I have two nodes "Foo" and "Foo Bar".  Running any of the following Cypher queries in the browser interface works fine - returning either one or both nodes:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index("Name:Foo") match n RETURN n
START n=node:node_auto_index("Name:Foo*") match n RETURN n
```

However, running the following query returns a Neo database error (Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure) - note the space in the name:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index("Name:Foo Bar") match n RETURN n
```

I'm at a loss as to what this issue might be - is this an error with my search request, or a known problem with the database?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string supplied to `node:node_auto_index` is passed directly to the index provider (which is Lucene by default). There Lucene query syntax applies, see: http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html.

Space is a term separator in your case, so you might try:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index("Name:'Foo Bar'") match n RETURN n
```

(Actually - it's as per Stefan's comment below:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index('Name:"Foo Bar"') match n RETURN n
```

Thanks Stefan!)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, Stefan.  I'm sorry - I should have mentioned that I tried this when looking at the issue originally.  Using single quotations as you have them above gives the same Execution Failure error.  Interestingly, using "Name:'Foo'" in the above actually returns zero records (no error), whereas "Name:Foo" returns a node.  Is there a possibility that I have not set up my indexing correctly?  From your answer, it appears that the format you suggest is *expected* to work ...

Comment: try it the other way round: `'Name:"Foo Bar"'`. Maybe Lucene is picky about `'` vs `"`.

Comment: Ah!  And, of course, I didn't try that.  You're entirely correct - it works as {START n=node:node_auto_index('Name:"Foo Bar"') match n RETURN n}.  Many thanks for your help, Stefan.

Comment: you can also do `START n=node:node_auto_index(Name="Foo Bar") match n RETURN n`