# Neo4j: setting up full-text index and fuzzy search cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4j 2.1.1, I am trying to set up a full-text node index on the `aliases` property.
My data looks like following:

[image]

I have managed to set up the index, called `Aliases` (see screenshots below). However, cypher query such as this

`START n=node:Aliases('aliases:Distressed\\ Debt') RETURN n`

returned 0 rows.

I followed [the advice given here](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/) and had recreated the data, even restarted the server.

Index successfully created (via POSTMAN):
[image]

... and it is visible in the Neo4j Webadmin

[image]

Contents of `neo4j.properties` settings file:

`keep_logical_logs=true
node_auto_indexing=true
node_keys_indexable=name,name_long,name_short,bbg,aliases
relationship_auto_indexing=true`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not using a schema index?

Comment: Check out this answer. It shows how to include a space in your property name.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177602/neo4j-database-execution-error-searching-against-an-index-with-a-node-name-conta/24179712#24179712

Comment: @JimBiard, schema index doesn't support fuzzy matching. Full-text index does. See also [different treatment of whitespaces](http://www.sinking.in/blog/seven-databases-neo4j-and-misunderstanding-indexes/) and different syntax [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887087/neo4j-2-cypher-fuzzy-search) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450308/full-text-search-in-neo4j-with-spaces). The answer you linked doesn't work.

Comment: To simplify further, I avoided whitespace by searching for `START n=node:Aliases('aliases:"Distressed"~0.9') RETURN n` or `START n=node:Aliases('aliases:"Distressed*"') RETURN n` but again, 0 rows returned in both cases.

Comment: Another try with syntax from [blog](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/) by @MichaelHunger : `START n=node:Aliases("aliases:Distressed*") RETURN n`. Returned 0 rows.

Comment: Does your index actually return ANY data? `START n=node:Aliases("*:*") RETURN n`

Comment: @Wouter great diagnostic test and thanks for that. `START n=node:Aliases("*:*") RETURN n` returns 0 rows. I was concerned whether I configured the index properly from the very beginning. Any guidelines? So far, I've followed the abovementioned [blog](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/), even populated the index manually: `MATCH (n) WHERE has(n.aliases) SET n.aliases=n.aliases RETURN COUNT(*)` returned `COUNT(*) 2` ( I indeed have only two test nodes with `aliases` property)

Comment: Sorry I do not have any experience with auto indexing, we only use legacy indexing via the java api. Our needs are too specific to use auto indexing..